# flutter: Exception DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new in flutter and I am not able to solve this issue can anyone help me?
I am able to get data in string if I type `Future<String> login()` instead of `Future<WrappedResponse> login()` this and it will print on Presenter class which is given below.

This is my api class

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:ceee_app/converters/wrapped_response.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';

part 'api_service.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://******.com/_dev/api/v1/")
abstract class RestClient {
  factory RestClient(Dio dio) = _RestClient;

  @FormUrlEncoded()
  @POST("login")
  Future<WrappedResponse> login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password, @Field("device_token") String token, @Field("device_type") String type);
}
```

This is my wrapper class

```
import 'package:ceee_app/model/user.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'wrapped_response.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()

class WrappedResponse{
  @JsonKey(name: "message")
  String message;
  @JsonKey(name: "status")
  String status;
  @JsonKey(name: "result")
  User data;

  WrappedResponse();

  factory WrappedResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$WrappedResponseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$WrappedResponseToJson(this);

}
```

This is my user class

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part "user.g.dart";

@JsonSerializable()
class User{
  @JsonKey()
  int id;
  @JsonKey()
  String name;
  @JsonKey()
  String l_name;
  @JsonKey()
  String email;
  @JsonKey()
  String session_token;
  @JsonKey()
  String device_token;

  User();

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);

}
```

This is my Presenter class

```
import 'package:ceee_app/contracts/login_activity_contract.dart';
import 'package:ceee_app/model/user.dart';
import 'package:ceee_app/webservices/api_service.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginActivityPresenter implements LoginActivityInteractor {
  LoginActivityView view;
  LoginActivityPresenter(this.view);
  RestClient api = RestClient(Dio());

  @override
  void success(String token) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString("api_token", token);
  }

  @override
  void destroy() => view = null;

  @override
  void login(String email, String password, String token, String type) async {
    await api.login(email, password, token, type).then((it){
      debugPrint("Data : "+it.toString());

    }).catchError((e){
      print("Exception $e");
      view?.toast("There is an error!");
    });
  }
}
```

And my response is

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Login successful!",
  "result": {
    "id": 20,
    "session_token": "YXBpX3Rva2VuNWY3YzJmODM2ZTgyNjUuNTY1MjUwNzAxNjAxOTc0MTQ3",
    "name": "abd",
    "l_name": "xyz",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "device_token": "fKrw8mpYT96fWIfaxrF26r:APA91bGZUW1wGSmdNMNb",
  }
}
```

Comment: Is content-type text/plain or application/json?

Answer (score 6):

I got response as string. But i have converted as JSON using following steps:

```
  final dio = Dio();        
    dio.interceptors.add(JsonResponseConverter());
            
        json_response_convert.dart
        
            import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
            import 'dart:convert';
            
            class JsonResponseConverter extends Interceptor {
              @override
              void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
                response.data = json.decode(response.data);
                super.onResponse(response, handler);
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the required constructor parameters for JSON serialization.

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class WrappedResponse{
  @JsonKey(name: "message")
  String message;
  @JsonKey(name: "status")
  String status;
  @JsonKey(name: "result")
  User data;

  WrappedResponse({this.message, this.status, this.data});

  factory WrappedResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$WrappedResponseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$WrappedResponseToJson(this);
}
```

The same applies to the `User` class.

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class User{
  ...
  User({this.name, this.l_name, this.email, session_token, this.device_token});  
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the endpoint response header to application/json.

The problem is that the header of the endpoint returns text/plain or just not application/json.

But for the retrofit to parse automatically, it needs this "application/json" specific type of header.

Hopes it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have control over the method created with Retrofit, we can capture the data from the response and decode it using JSONDecode.

```
Dio dio = Dio();

dio.interceptors.add(JsonResponseInterceptor());
```

```
class JsonResponseInterceptor extends Interceptor 
{
  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {

    response.data = json.decode(response.data);

    super.onResponse(response, handler);

  }

}
```

Its place in my code is

```
const String APPLICATION_JSON = 'application/json';
const String CONTENT_TYPE = 'content-type';
const String ACCEPT = 'accept';
const String AUTHORIZATION = 'authorization';
const String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'language';

class DioFactory {
  AppPreferences _appPreferences;

  DioFactory(this._appPreferences);

  Future<Dio> getDio() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    int _timeOut = 60 * 1000;
    String language = await _appPreferences.getAppLanguage();

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      CONTENT_TYPE: APPLICATION_JSON,
      ACCEPT: APPLICATION_JSON,
      AUTHORIZATION: Constant.token,
      DEFAULT_LANGUAGE: language,
    };
    dio.interceptors.add(JsonResponseInterceptor());  // here ____________________________________________ 

    dio.options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: Constant.baseUrl,
      connectTimeout: _timeOut,
      receiveTimeout: _timeOut,
      headers: headers,
    );

    if (kReleaseMode) {
      print("release mode on logs");
    } else {
      dio.interceptors.add(PrettyDioLogger(
        requestHeader: true,
        requestBody: true,
        responseHeader: true,
      ));
    }

    return dio;
  }
}

class JsonResponseInterceptor extends Interceptor {  // here ____________________________________________ 
  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    response.data = json.decode(response.data);
    super.onResponse(response, handler);
  }
}
```